# Signal Input/Output Relationship Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a neural network using tensorflow to predict a vibration output from a given actuator input. I have 500 sample input/output signals that can be used for training and testing. Most of the examples in the tensorflow tutorial are for classification, so I'm currently stumped. My input is a series of 6 digital signals from -1 to 1 and my output is an analog signal(1000 samples). Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: So is there a specific estimator I could use for problem? If not, what kind of model and optimizer should I use to train this input output relationship? Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Welcome but see _Rome wasn't built in a day_ - this is what Machine Learning (in fact whole Science) is all about: Testing different algorithms and parameters and gradually reach the optimum ones. I think you should start from some tutorial first.

Comment: I went over several tutorials and found that image recognition is the closest example to my problem. However, there is nothing close to my problem. I suppose tensorflow may not work for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I can understand so far is you need to predict the vibration output, hence you need to apply either Regression or Signal Estimation techniques we study in Statistical Signal Processing

Comment: Ok, I will look into these techniques. I'm new to machine learning and have a project deadline, so I needed a direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no *right* answer for this as there are many algorithms you could try to find the optimal one. From the description you've given, I'd start with the Tensorflow [LinearRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor) estimator.

If you provide some sample data, it may make it easier to help you.